# Purpose of PartialOrdering in Scala library

Tags: scala, math, standard-library

I understand what is [partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) from mathematical point of view, but cannot see where and how [PartialOrdering](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.0/scala/math/PartialOrdering.html) type class from Scala library can be used. I searched through whole standard library and there's only one usage: it extended by Ordering. Same story for its primary method `tryCompare`, it seems isn't used anywhere.

So, what benefits I can have if instead of

```
case class Foo(x: Int, y: String)

val order = Ordering.by { foo => (foo.x, foo.y) }
```

I implement a more domain-correct instance:

```
object PartialFoo extends PartialOrdering[Foo] {
  def tryCompare(a: Foo, b: Foo): Option[Foo] = {
    if (a.x != b.x) None  // Doesn't make sense to compare foos with different xs
    else ???
  }
}
```

**UPD**: It also seems like Ordering trait [defined](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/math/Ordering.scala#L75) with return type `Some[Int]` (not `Option[Int]`) and I even cannot use override. Is it intentional?

Comment: The standard library is full of mysteries like this, and I'm not sure there's a better answer than "someone successfully argued for including this at some point".

Comment: Also, the only place I can remember ever seeing this used in any Scala codebase is Algebird.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a template for **type classes** which would represent natural partial orderings for a type.

The point of these classes isn't to be used explicitly, but implicitly in libraries which would allow a user to have access to methods which could only be applied to types with such a natural type class available.

As an example, the `Numeric` type class, which is for instance an implicit parameter of the `sum` method of collections, is never actually explicitly provided when doing something like `val x = List(1, 2, 3).sum`.
Instead, scala by default imports a `Numeric[Int]` object in scope, which allows the compiler to "know" how to sum ints.

Similarly, if one were to develop a method which would only "work" for elements with a natural partial ordering, there would be two options :

1. create a trait of the likes of `PartiallyOrdered` and require arguments of this type - this is not very flexible, just compare to the sum method, which can be called on ANY collection
2. add an implicit parameter of type `PartialOrdering[T]`to the method, and create implementations for the desired types.

Although I can't find any actual implementations of PartialOrdering which do not also implement Ordering, having this class is still a good thing, as it means any users which would like to implement PartialOrdering, but not Ordering, **will also be able to pass Orderings** to their method using PartialOrdering's ! eg. Int, String, etc.

So say I create a class `A` and a partial ordering

`APartialOrdering extends PartialOrdering[A]`.

Because my type `A` admits no natural ordering, only a partial one. Finally, I create a method

`def doSomethingForPartiallyOrdered[T](t: T)(implicit po: PartialOrdering[T]) = _`

Now, I can pass objects of type `A`, but also Int's, Strings, etc.

Comment: I'm assuming the OP knows what type classes are and how they're encoded in Scala—that doesn't seem to be the question. Also it's unclear what your last sentence means—it's certainly not possible to provide a `PartialOrdering` where an `Ordering` is expected.

Comment: No, but it's possible to provide an Ordering in place of a Partial Ordering. I'll make it clearer